# Multiple banners, widgets and promotions?

Tags: promotions, widget

I've got an interesting scenario that I can't quite figure out. Here's what I've got going on:

First, I have a Welcome promotion driven with a coupon for all customers in all customer groups. I have a banner rotator widget which shows a banner in the top block of all pages if the coupon is applied. Works fine.

Next, I have another promotion which is applied to a customer group called Sale. This promotion also displays a banner in the topmost block of all pages so long as a customer from the sale group is logged in. Works fine.

Here's the thing: I don't want to offer both promotions to the Sale customer as the Sale promotion will be a better discount than the Welcome promotion. No problem. I make sure that the Sale promotion has a higher priority than the Welcome promotion and then I make sure that the Sale promotion's "Stop  Further Rules From Processing" setting is set to Yes.

My expectation is that when I applied the welcome coupon I should see the welcome banner at the page top, but if I log in a sale customer and apply the Welcome coupon and the Sale coupon, I should **only** see the Sale banner, since the Welcome discount isn't applied.  What actually happens is that I see both banners.

Any ideas as to why this would happen or if I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so I've done some exploring here and my apparent conclusion is that Magento is only able to display **one** promotional banner on the site at one time.  The widget/banner functionality is not intelligent enough to recognize specific conditions for multiple rules applied at once. Either that, or it's a bug.  It's a bummer either way.